# List value of a dict goes infinite depth during iteration

Tags: python, nested, iteration

Here is a puzzling question. I have a dict with list values. I iterate over this dict twice: a normal iteration first, and then a second iteration where I assign an index to the iteration variable. This ends up modifying the last dict value and it becomes of infinite depth (the 3 dots signify that the list is infinite depth).

Here is a simple example:

**Input Code**:

```py
a = {1 : [2], 3: [4]}                       

for i,j in a.items(): 
  pass 

for i,j[0] in a.items(): 
  pass

print(a)
```

**Output**:

```
{1: [2], 3: [[...]]}
```

How does this happen?

Comment: If you skip the first iteration, you would get an error because you can't reference `j[0]` if `j` has not been defined.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks. Yes. I had a `j` from a previous run, so it wasn't showing error for me. But yes it will show error in a fresh run. I am modifying the quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your first iteration, `j` is the last value in your dictionary, `[3]`.

You then iterate through the dictionary again, setting `j[0]` to each value in the dictionary. Since `j` is referring to a list inside your dictionary, it is that list inside the dictionary that you are altering. And the final effect of the alteration is that `j[0]` is the last value in the dictionary: `j` itself.

If you skipped the first iteration, you would either get a `NameError` because you can't reference `j[0]` without first defining `j`; or you would be mutating some different list from a previous usage of the variable `j`.